# Handling change of a timezone in a watch face

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-2.0, watch-face-api

If you take a look at [Google's example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WatchFace/blob/88ae4adfabdcf3c432d957b84f6fe069b3c8ed14/Wearable/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/watchface/watchface/AnalogComplicationWatchFaceService.java#L186-L193) of an analog watch face you can see that they are handling timezone change using `BroadcastReceiver`.

In [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceService.Engine#onTimeTick()), it says that `onTimeTick` will be triggered by timezone change. Would it be enough to just update timezone data every time when `onTimeTick` is called?

The only problem that I see is that `mCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());` will be called on every `onTimeTick` call, but it's not heavy operation, so I don't really see any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the example is just outdated. When I started building watch faces the `onTimeTick()` method would not be called if you e.g. changed the date or time zone from Settings on your paired device. You had to register a `BroadcastReceiver` to catch those events.

I'm not sure when this stopped being the case, but currently `onTimeTick()` seems to be called for all events related to updating time, date, and time zone.

We use an `android.text.format.Time` object and update its `timezone` field whenever `onTimeTick()` is called.

I guess you could optimize this slightly by only setting it if it has changed. However, like you mentioned in your question, this isn't an expensive operation. I doubt that this change would make a noticeable improvement.

Much more important is to make sure that you don't run the watch face code that handles time zone changes unless it has actually changed. That would trigger unnecessary (and expensive) redraw operations.